# KA24DE motor terminology?

Tags: engine, nissan

I'm trying to post / sell a "KA24DE", but I'm confused about the phrasing.

- Does "KA24DE" need to be all caps like I have it?
- Is this a Nissan motor or a motor with a transmission?
- Is there a difference in a tranny & a transmission?

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen it spelled in lower case,  when referring to motor groups and types it is proper to use all caps.  The KA you are trying to sell is just the motor. No, there isn't a difference between tranny and transmission.  "Tranny" is slang for transmission and I only like to use the slang term when verbally talking about transmissions.

Trying to find a buyer for your KA might be hard as they are deliberately removed from 240 and replaced with such motors like SR20 or RB line so you would have to come across someone that wants their 240 back to stock or I believe the Nissan hard body trucks also came with the KA.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few things going on here:

- **capitalization of the engine name:** each engine and each manufacturer has their own convention for uppercase/lowercase. In this case, this engine has it's name properly typed in all uppercase.
- **is it just the engine:** well, nobody here knows because we haven't seen what you have. You'll have to post a picture. The transmission is bolted onto the engine, and it isn't uncommon for people to remove both as a unit. Then again, sometimes people remove them separately.
- **tranny vs transmission:** "tranny" is a colloquial term for transmission, just like I call my 20 pound sledge hammer "sudo" (for my computer geek friends out there), and just like I call my 18 inch pipe wrench "stupid seized rounded off nut remover," and just like I call my left and right hands "Fred" and "Barney", respectively.

To help you figure out whether or not it's just the engine, here's a pic of a similar engine without the tranny (there's that word again. Not my fault, Fred and Barney are the ones typing.) The transmission attaches at the lower right side on this picture.
[image]

And here's a picture of a similar engine with the transmission. The transmission is the single long ice cream cone shaped thing at the very bottom of this picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just one more thing: The Term KA24DE refers to the engine, not to a engine + transmission combination.

- **KA**: KA Series Engine
- **24**: 2.4 Litre dispacement
- **D**: [DOHC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_camshaft#Double_overhead_camshaft)
- **E**: Electronic Port Fuel Injection